# Subversion: Track defects that are part of build

Tags: svn, build-process

All development commits happen on branches. We mandate entering defect numbers in commit log. But, once the branches are merged to trunk, there are no records of the defect numbers. I am looking for some advise on tracking defects that are part of a build done from trunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, once the branches are merged to trunk, there are no records of the defect numbers.

You need to use the `--use-merge-history` option, or `-g` for short. `svn log -g` will include the commit messages of the merged commits.

If you use TortoiseSVN, you can check the "Include merged revisions" checkbox in the [log dialog](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).

Comment: Googled for such functionality in TortoiseSVN, without any luck. Is there such an option?

Comment: @publicRavi like I said, enable the "Include merged revisions" checkbox in TortoiseSVN's log dialog. Documentation with screenshot: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach could be to make use of the svn:mergeinfo property.

Run this on your trunk branch

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo <trunk_url>
```

In there should be a complete list of the revisions that have been merged into the trunk.  Here is an example of what you might find

```
/branches/ver1:10-20,25,27
/branches/ver2:34,36,38-42
```

Now you can use `svn log` to get the commit logs of those merged revisions and extract the defect numbers.  Something like

```
svn log /branches/ver1 -r10:20 --xml
```

I think a script could be easily written to automate this process.